# Get random number from array every 24 hours

Tags: php

I would like to know if it would be possible to retrieve a value from an array and use that value for the entire day without changing the value on refresh, it will be used for a discount section. So everyday one of the random values will be taken and that value will be applied as discount % for the next 24 hours. Tomorrow (24 hours later) it will take another value and use that value for the next 24 hours.

I created a logical statement below but isn't working. Any help will be gladly appreciated to complete below function.

```
      //TIME VALUES
      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
      $currentTime = date('H:i');
      $dayStartTime = '00:01';
      $dayEndTime = '23:59';

      if($currentTime >= $dayStartTime && $currentTime <= $dayEndTime) {
        $items = Array("10","15","20");
        echo $items[array_rand($items)];
      }
```

Thank you for you time.
Dane

Comment: You need to save your data somewhere persistent, be it a database, or a file, or a cache element with 24 hours expiration.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. Store it somewhere though.

Comment: Yes, there are several options like using a flat/json file to store discount and date-time, update the same in next 24 hours.

Comment: I feel like this question could have value, but given its phrasing I think it's too opinion-based, since there are too many ways of achieving the same thing.

Comment: thank you, I will try by creating the values in the database and put a 24 hours expiration on to that.

Comment: which will be the simplest way to achieve the above?

Comment: create a text file, that has something like `2018-08-24 00:00:00,15` (where 15 is the day's random number). then in your script, read the line of text in from the file, explode on the comma, check the date is less than 24 hours ago, and if so use the number, if not, overwrite the file with fresh info.

Comment: You could make use of a cron job to call the file every 24 hours.

Comment: or yes better still, get a cron to update it then your code will only ever read the file and use the value

Comment: I agree with using a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to store a discount somewhere. This will at minimum have 2 fields: `amount` and `expiry`.

On load, check if there's a valid discount:

```
SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE expiry > NOW() LIMIT 1;
```

If a result is returned, use it. If not, create a new discount with an expiry of 24 hours and use that.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out and see how that goes. Much appreciated

Comment: Thank you everyone for the support. I have used 'OK Sure's' suggestion which was also recommended by 'GiamPy' and what I was looking for is working 100% perfect according to my needs.
Thank you once again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and for marking solved, @Dane